# dealing with extractors on case classes with an invariant type parameter

Tags: scala, match, type-parameter

I think, my issue is best described by some sample code:

```
 class Foo[T] 
 class Bar extends Foo[String] 
 class Baz extends Foo[Int] 


 trait X { def f: Foo[_] }
 case class Wrapper[D](f: Foo[D]) extends X
 val w: X = Wrapper(new Bar)
 w match { case Wrapper(_: Bar) => 1 }
```

The last line fails with

```
  found   : Bar
  required: Foo[Any]
  Note: String <: Any (and Bar <: Foo[String]), but class Foo is invariant in type T.
  You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

I understand that this happens because `unapply` is defined with a type parameter, which is inferred as `Any`, and so it complains about `String` being incompatible.

But the question is if there is any way to make it work? I tried giving a type parameter to the exctractor, like this:  `w match { case Wrapper[String](_: Bar) => 1 }`, but it says it does not take parameters (which is a lie) ...  :(

The only way I came up with so far is this ugly baby:

```
 w match { case w: Wrapper[String] if w.f.isInstanceOf[Bar]  => 1 }
```

or, maybe,

```
Option(w).map(_.f) match { case Some(_: Bar) => 1 }
```

(the latter works because `Option` is covariant, but I can't make my classes covariant unfortunately). Also, I can't really use the last alternative without some additional ugliness IRL, because the equivalent of `X` in real life doesn't actually have `f`.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Define custom extractor

`Wrapper.unapply` does take type parameter, but you cannot specify one* in a pattern match sequence, so compiler infers one for you (and if compiler does that, it's very often `Any` or `Nothing`).

And, actually, you don't want it to, because you're removing your type information when you coerce your element to type `X`. So, you want a matcher for existential version

```
object WrapperEx {
  def unapply(w: Wrapper[_]): Option[Foo[_]] = Wrapper.unapply(w)
}
```

And use it like so:

```
w match { case WrapperEx(_: Bar) => 1 }
```

Runnable version [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oleg-py/DmQV0AjAT3mpwQrs6wFfvw)

- Good news: you can delegate to generated case class matcher.
- Bad news: you cannot define it inside case class companion. Scala is happily picking the wrong one already, so it won't be able to disambiguate.

Still, I'd say it's not half-bad

---

* you can in latest Typelevel Scala, but I'm not sure how it works with type casts and I could not get it to work for your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize `trait X` to get rid of existential type in `def f: Foo[_]`, I think this is what trips the compiler up. The following code works:

```
class Foo[T]
class Bar extends Foo[String]
class Baz extends Foo[Int]

trait X[A] { def f: Foo[A] }
case class Wrapper[D](f: Foo[D]) extends X[D]
val w: X[String] = Wrapper(new Bar) // type ascription can be omitted and will be inferred
w match { case Wrapper(_: Bar) => 1 }
```

Comment: Well, perhaps, I oversimplified my example. 
The actual use case is more like `Seq(new Bar, new Baz) match { case Seq(Wrapper(_: Bar), Wrapper(_: Baz)) }`, so, this doesn't really help :(

Comment: Yeah, in that case type of Seq would be `Seq[Wrapper[_ >: Int with String]]`, which makes little sense.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "little sense" ... The type of `Seq` is actually `Seq[X]`. But I don't see much wrong with `Seq[Wrapper[_ >: Int with String]]` or `Seq[Wrapper[_]]` either.

Comment: Right, in your example, where type X isn't parameterized, it would be `Seq[X]`, which is fine. But in my example, where type X is parameterized, I personally feel that type `Seq[Wrapper[_ >: Int with String]]` provides little of useful information. I'm not sure how could one practically use that `Int with String`.

Comment: Well, `Int with String` just tells you that the parameter is going to be either `Int` or `String`. One practical use of it is actually the case matching. 
In any event, if it's not useful in a particular case, you can always shorten it to `Seq[Wrapper[_]]` ...